# How can I resolve this figure margin issue caused by geometry margin options?

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, geometry

[image: Caption margin issue]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\caption{\emph{Title.} \blindtext}
\label{fig:mipLevels}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For some reason the `geometry` package options cause the gap which I highlighted in the picture above. What can I do to fix it?

(I’m using `@{}` to remove the spacing left and right of the `tabular*` environment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) nor with your construction of the figure. Instead, it's the default space left above a bottom-placed caption. This length is controlled by `\abovecaptionskip`.

Below I've dropped the use of a fixed-width `tabular*` but produced the same layout. Each image has width `0.3333\linewidth-1.3333\tabcolsep`. The first part of the figure has the regular `\abovecaptionskip` (of 10pt), while the second has it reduced by 50% (to 5pt):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy} \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy} \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy}

  \bigskip

  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy} \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy} \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy}
  \caption{\emph{Title.} \blindtext}

  \bigskip
  \hrulefill
  \par\bigskip\bigskip

  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{.5\abovecaptionskip}% Reduce \abovecaptionskip by 50%
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy} \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy} \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy}

  \bigskip

  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy} \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy} \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-1.333\tabcolsep,height=2cm]{dummy}
  \caption{\emph{Title.} \blindtext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\arraystretch` is set to 3. That means also the descender part of the strut box is multiplied by 3. But the `\includegraphics` lines do not have a descender part, thus that part is filled with white space.

The example does the opposite, setting `\arraystretch` to 0 and the vertical gap is set explicitly to `2\tabcolsep` as the horizontal gap (adjust to your needs).

Also the example calculates the width for the images to allow the table to occupy the full text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\newcommand*{\imgwidth}{%
  \dimexpr(\linewidth-4\tabcolsep)/3\relax
}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=2cm]{dummy} &
  \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=2cm]{dummy}&
  \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=2cm]{dummy}\\[2\tabcolsep]
  \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=2cm]{dummy} &
  \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=2cm]{dummy}&
  \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\caption{\emph{Title.} \blindtext}
\label{fig:mipLevels}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]